# Resolving to correct dependencies when loading classes with custom classloaders

Tags: java

So I have this generic backend server that loads shaded jars in memory and then loads it through a custom Classloader.

E.g.

```
MyClass class = c.newInstance();
```

It works fine until the shaded Jar dependencies conflicts with the server classes.

E.g.

Server contains (with Custom Classloader):

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.jackson-databind:2.6.0
```

While the shaded jar contains

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.jackson-databind:2.9.9
```

When the method in the class that requires the said library e.g. `class.doSomeThing();` it throws an error `Caused by java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:` because the loaded `jackson-databind is 2.6.0` instead of `2.9.9`

The question here is when the class is loaded from the shaded jar is there a way to make sure that the shaded dependencies are the ones used?

Answer (score 0):

> The question here is when the class is loaded from the shaded jar is there a way to make sure that the shaded dependencies are the ones used?

If you are using the default Class loader then the order of resolution will work as the order of the classpath. Within your code you can use

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("system.class.path").replaceAll(":", "\n"));
```

And inspect the classpath. Usually such runtime environment (for example apache spark) has such [features](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) to allow you to prepend the classpath. You can check with your runtime server environment for such feature.